# How to use reflection with multiple classes extending the base class in java

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I am very new to reflections and I would like to get some advices/help. I am trying to get the subclass names using reflection in the base class.  I have multiple subclasses (Cat, Dog, Frog etc..) and all of them extend the base class (Animal).

What I want to do is getting the class names from the subclasses themselves and pass them through the constructors so the Animal does not have to instantiate dozens of subclasses. Below is an example of what I am NOT trying to do.

If there is a way to just dynamically get the subclasses names without going through the pain of instantiating every single subclass, I would love to see it. Your help is much appreciated.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    private String s;

    public Dog() {
        s = "Bark";
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Dogs " + s);
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    private String s;

    public Cat() {
        s = "Meow";
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Cats " + s);
    }
}

class Animal {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Class cls = dog.getClass();
        System.out.println("The name of class is " + cls.getName());
        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor();
        System.out.println("The name of constructor is " + constructor.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection for this?

Comment: This is not the actual project I want to use reflection for. I used it as an example to illustrate what I was trying to say

Comment: Instead of using reflection, you could create an abstract method on `Animal` – `getName()` or something – and then each subclass would implement that method to return whatever the thing is ("Dog", "Cat", etc.). Then with any instance of `Animal`, you could call `animal.getName()` and get the right answer.

Comment: Perhaps you want a [class literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), like `Dog.class` or `Cat.class`?  Or are you trying to list all existing subclasses of `Animal`?

Comment: Recommended reads: [Creating Extensible Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) of the tutorial and [the `ServiceLoader` API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you want the names of the subclasses. If the problem is to instantiate a class based on its name it would be better to use an Abstract Factory pattern. You can create an enumeration that contains the animal that you knows

```
enum ANIMALS {
    DOG, CAT
  }
```

You can create the Animal interface

```
public interface Animal {

}
```

the classes extending Animal as default classes

```
public class Dog implements Animal {

}
```

then finally the AnimalAbstractFactory as

```
  public class AnimalAbstractFactory {

  public enum ANIMALS {
    DOG, CAT
  }

  public Animal createAnimal(ANIMALS animal) {
    switch (animal) {
      case DOG:
        return new Dog();
      case CAT:
        return new Cat();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Notes that now you do not need to know the subclass to instantiate an animal. Note also that *createAnimal* returns an **Animal** not the subclass. I hope it helps.

Comment: The code above is just an example of how I do not want to use reflection. Not the actual. I have dozens of subclasses that extend the base class and I am trying to get their class names if they are invoked for example. The only way I thought about it was to instantiate every single subclass in the base class to get each name (like the example above). This is not an efficient approach. I am trying to see how I can use reflection more efficiently